# MKAnnotation Not Conform to Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I am new to iOS programming and having a problem extending my LocationA class to conform to the MKAnnotation protocol.

The LocationA class is:

```
import MapKit

class LocationA {
    let name: String
    let identifier: String
    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees

    init (name: String, identifier: String, latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
        self.name = name
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    } }
```

The extended version is:

```
import MapKit

extension LocationA: MKAnnotation, NSObject {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
    var title: String! {
        return identifier
    }
    var subtitle: String! {
        return name
    }
}
```

It appears that I have implemented all the attributes required by the protocol but I am still getting "Not Conform to Protocol" error. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You cannot extend with the class `NSObject`. Move it to the class declaration in the beginning (`class LocationA : NSObject`)

Comment: Just put MKAnnotation as a parent of your class declaration i.e. no need for the extension and get rid of NSObject

Comment: Thanks guys! Indeed `class LocationA: NSObject` is needed.